# why the for loop is using out of range values?

Tags: c, loops, character, user-input

In this code below the loop must end at the 4th value as it is the ending of loop but instead of it,It starts using values that doesn't even follows the condition of loop i.e-100 and even it's not stopping also..I came to know about it when i put a printf statement to test this and then I found its using 100 in a[i] which is not possible..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,m;
    i=0;
    char a[i];
    printf("how many characters you want to enter=");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %c",&a[i]);
        printf("%d\n",i);
        //now this loop is not stopping//
    }
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("%c \t",a[i]);
    }

}
```

OUTPUT:-

```
how many characters you want to enter=4                                                              
a                                                                                                    
1                                                                                                    
b                                                                                                    
2                                                                                                    
c                                                                                                    
3                                                                                                    
d                                                                                                    
100                                                                                                  
e                                                                                                    
101
```

Comment: `i=0;; char a[i];` declare an array of 0 elements. Do `scanf("%d",&n);char a[n];` allowing to have its size . First index of an array is 0, not 1, so replace `for (i=1;i<=n;i++)` by `for (i=0;i<n;i++)`. I also encourage you to check `scanf("%d",&n);`returns 1 and *n* is positive

Comment: This doesn't work i already tried this..

Comment: I put an answer, please read it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...
>
> ```
> //now this loop is not stopping//
> ```
>
> ...
>
> OUTPUT:-
>
> ```
> ...
> d
> 100
> e
> 101
> ```

this (undefined) behavior is the result of writing out of your array wrongly sized 0, *i* becomes 100 after you enter 'd' then 101 after you enter 'e' because the ASCII code of 'd' and 'e' are 100 and 101.

As I said in my remark :

> `i=0;; char a[i];` declare an array of 0 elements. Do `scanf("%d",&n);char a[n];` allowing to have its size . First index of an array is 0, not 1, so replace `for (i=1;i<=n;i++)` by `for (i=0;i<n;i++)`. I also encourage you to check `scanf("%d",&n);` returns 1 and *n* is positive

so I do not understand why you reply :

> This doesn't work i already tried this

except if you missed at least one correction from my remark, because doing all I said :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int n;
  
  printf("how many characters you want to enter=");
  
  if ((scanf("%d",&n) != 1) || (n < 1))
    puts("invalid size");
  else {
    char a[n];
    int i;
    
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
      scanf(" %c",&a[i]);
      printf("%d\n",i);
    }

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c \t",a[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall cc.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
how many characters you want to enter=4
a
0
b
1
c
2
d
3
a   b   c   d   
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Comment: Sorry actually i misunderstood that you wanted to say...you are right i did it again and got the correct output thanks for help and sorry for my silly mistake..

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0;
char a[i];
```

Is [undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) so **wrong**. You should allocate an [automatic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) which is a non-empty array, or preferably use carefully [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/), see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...). Be sure to read the documentation of every standard function (e.g. [of `scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)) before using it. Notice that `scanf` can fail and returns an interesting integer which you should test.

If you use GCC, compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`